# How to access attributes of the __init_ function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, arguments

is there a way to access attributes of **init** without assigning them to self.attribute = attribute
For example:

```
class test:
def __init__(self, o = "hi"):
   pass

def f(self):
    print(o)

j = test()
j.f()
```

I want that the __init__argument get printed without assigning self.o = o in the constructor and using print(self.o) in f

I just want to spare code, for example by using something like that in the print statement of f: print(test.**init**.o) or something like that

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: Is what you want something like [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)?

Comment: *without assigning self.o = o* why? `def func(a): return b`? you are asking something like this.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say with "attributes of `__init__`", but it's almost certainly not what that actually means. At any rate, it's not remotely clear *why* you want to do something like this. The *entire point* of having a class is to bundle together data in a useful way, to represent some sort of abstraction.

Comment: It comes across like you just find the syntax annoying or that it has too much boilerplate. I assure you there are very good reasons for these design decisions, and there is much less boilerplate involved here than in most other languages.At any rate, that makes the question [off topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I just want to spare code, for example by using something like that in the print statement of f: print(test.__init__.o) or something like that

Comment: @coderxXx "I want to spare code" Can you rephrase this? It sounds like you left out a word. Do you mean "I want to avoid unnecessary code"?

Comment: No answer to the comments during 10 hours. Question will be closed until it becomes clear what asker wants to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, while this is possible, using some of Python's inspection capabilities:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, o="hi"):
        pass
    def f(self):
        print(self.__init__.__func__.__defaults__[0])

j = test()
j.f()
# hi
```

what is the point of it?

Function parameters are local to the function for good reason: to be used there and *only* there.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, o="hi"):
        self.o = o
    def f(self):
        print(self.o)
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought there was a less complicated syntax in Python

Comment: No, `__defaults__` is a plain tuple.

Comment: Instead of using [0] is it also possible to use the arguments name?